# Set notify-osd font to the Ubuntu Font Family

Tags: lubuntu, notify-osd

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit. I didn't like xfce-notifyd, so I installed libnotify. However, it does not use the Ubuntu font (I think it uses the Sans font), and it looks quite ugly because of that. How do I change it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: In Ubuntu it's set to the uff, so it must be changable, since I'm using the same package.

Comment: I literally just looked in notify-osd: https://imgur.com/YnNtvmg

Comment: How? What app is that?

Comment: It's called notify-osd: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig`

Comment: Already got notify-osd, but not the patched one... but it can't change the font anyway, thanks though.